# error: `line` does not live long enough (but I know it does)

Tags: rust

I am trying to make some kind of ffi to a library written in C, but got stuck. Here is a test case:

```rust
extern crate libc;
use libc::{c_void, size_t};

// this is C library api call
unsafe fn some_external_proc(_handler: *mut c_void, value: *const c_void,
                             value_len: size_t) {
    println!("received: {:?}" , std::slice::from_raw_buf(
             &(value as *const u8), value_len as usize));
}

// this is Rust wrapper for C library api
pub trait MemoryArea {
    fn get_memory_area(&self) -> (*const u8, usize);
}

impl MemoryArea for u64 {
    fn get_memory_area(&self) -> (*const u8, usize) {
        (unsafe { std::mem::transmute(self) }, std::mem::size_of_val(self))
    }
}

impl <'a> MemoryArea for &'a str {
    fn get_memory_area(&self) -> (*const u8, usize) {
        let bytes = self.as_bytes();
        (bytes.as_ptr(), bytes.len())
    }
}

#[allow(missing_copy_implementations)]
pub struct Handler<T> {
    obj: *mut c_void,
}

impl <T> Handler<T> {
    pub fn new() -> Handler<T> { Handler{obj: std::ptr::null_mut(),} }

    pub fn invoke_external_proc(&mut self, value: T) where T: MemoryArea {
        let (area, area_len) = value.get_memory_area();
        unsafe {
            some_external_proc(self.obj, area as *const c_void,
                               area_len as size_t)
        };
    }
}

// this is Rust wrapper user code
fn main() {
    let mut handler_u64 = Handler::new();
    let mut handler_str = Handler::new();

    handler_u64.invoke_external_proc(1u64); // OK
    handler_str.invoke_external_proc("Hello"); // also OK
    loop  {
        match std::io::stdin().read_line() {
            Ok(line) => {
                let key =
                    line.trim_right_matches(|&: c: char| c.is_whitespace());

                //// error: `line` does not live long enough
                // handler_str.invoke_external_proc(key)
            }
            Err(std::io::IoError { kind: std::io::EndOfFile, .. }) => break ,
            Err(error) => panic!("io error: {}" , error),
        }
    }
}
```

[Rust playpen](http://is.gd/dxtuOv)

I get "line does not live long enough" error if I uncomment line inside the loop. In fact, I realize that Rust is afraid that I could store short-living reference to a slice somewhere inside *Handler* object, but I quite sure that I wouldn't, and I also know, that it is safe to pass pointers to the external proc (actually, memory is immidiately copied at the C library side).

Is there any way for me to bypass this check?

Comment: You might be able to put the operation inside and "unsafe" block. See here: http://huonw.github.io/blog/2014/07/what-does-rusts-unsafe-mean/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are incorrectly parameterizing your struct, when you really want to do it for the function. When you create your current `Handler`, the struct will be specialized with a type that includes a lifetime. However, the lifetime of `line` is only for the block, so there *can be no lifetime for Handler* that lasts multiple loop iterations.

What you want is for the lifetime to be tied to the function call, not the life of the struct. As you noted, if you put the lifetime on the struct, then the struct is able to store references of that length. You don't need that, so put the generic type on the function instead:

```
impl Handler {
    pub fn new() -> Handler { Handler{obj: std::ptr::null_mut(),} }

    pub fn invoke_external_proc<T>(&mut self, value: T) where T: MemoryArea {
        let (area, area_len) = value.get_memory_area();
        unsafe {
            some_external_proc(self.obj, area as *const c_void,
                               area_len as size_t)
        };
    }
}
```

#### Amended answer

Since you want to specialize the struct on a type, but don't care too much about the lifetime of the type, let's try this:

```
#[allow(missing_copy_implementations)]
pub struct Handler<T: ?Sized> {
    obj: *mut c_void,
}

impl<T: ?Sized> Handler<T> {
    pub fn new() -> Handler<T> { Handler{ obj: std::ptr::null_mut() } }

    pub fn invoke_external_proc(&mut self, value: &T) where T: MemoryArea {
        let (area, area_len) = value.get_memory_area();
        unsafe {
            some_external_proc(self.obj, area as *const c_void,
                               area_len as size_t)
        };
    }
}
```

Here, we allow the type to be *unsized*. Since you can't pass an unsized value as a parameter, we now have to take a reference instead. We also have to change the `impl`:

```
impl MemoryArea for str {
    fn get_memory_area(&self) -> (*const u8, usize) {
        let bytes = self.as_bytes();
        (bytes.as_ptr(), bytes.len())
    }
}
```

Comment: I ran into a [similar problem myself](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/18549), and suggested Rust add a lint to protect against it.

Comment: Thank you for explanation, it really works for that testcase. But I actually need to parameterize the Handler struct: it has more than one method, where I need to have the same T type. Is there any solution to explicitly provide lifetime without removing struct parameter?

Comment: That's not how it works :-) You have to add `<T>` and `where` clauses to *every function*. Rust will specialize each function as appropriate. You only want to parameterize the struct when the struct **itself** uses the type parameter in a field. It's not just a way of DRYing up the parameter.

Comment: But what is the right way then for me to prevent providing u64 arg to *handler_str*? If I parametrize the function instead of struct I will be able to do such things easily.

Comment: That's a tough one. You want to be able to say "I will only ever accept strings, but I don't care about the lifetime of the string, so long as it's longer than the function call" with the additional complexity of "string" being a parameterized type.

Comment: @swizard Updated with an answer. I dunno if it's the *best answer*, but it works for your example.